# How to get Dailymotion title

Tags: php, video, title

Hi i am trying to get video title from dailymotion videos.

```
$imgid = $video_cek["embed"]; //this is dailymotion id (ex. xint71)
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed?
format=json&url=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$imgid"));
$video_cek['baslik']=$hash[0]['title'];
```

I cant find where is the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are returning JSON Format but trying to unserialize that, this should work:

```
$imgid = $video_cek["embed"];
$hash = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed?format=json&url=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$imgid"), true);
$video_cek['baslik']= $hash['title'];
```

Comment: Teşekkürler Ahmet.thx for help :)

Answer (score 0):

you get a json response, so use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

like:

```
$array = json_decode($hash, true);

echo $array['title'];
```

or

```
$array = json_decode($hash);

echo $array->title;
```

Comment: nope. He has to json_decode the $hash. Because the returning value is encoded :-)

Comment: dont forget the second parameter json_decode($hash,true); else it will return an object

Comment: or $array->title instead of $array['title'].. I edited that, but still waiting for beeing reviewed :)